# Oracle : How to rollback modifications in a View?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, rollback

Well, i mistakely modified a View, How can i rollback to the original one?
how can i access modifications history?
or is it lost forever?

Comment: Kindly ask the DBA to restore it from a back-up.

Comment: Unless you have a backed up version of the original view (e.g. in a source code repository), or ctrl-z works to undo your changes in whichever editor you have been working in, or some DBA has set up triggers to capture DDL changes, you're most likely out of luck.

Comment: the problem is that someone modified it in Oracle, without committing the changes on svn..

Comment: if  original view is in svn  then d you can use that re-create view

Comment: @Ramki that is the problem, they modified it without committing the changes to svn.

Comment: ok your correct view is not SVN ? then if you have DB backup you have to restore and go back before modification.

Comment: Is flashback query an option? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm

Comment: Change your perspective. The version in SVN is the right one, and any changes applied in the database on the fly should not exist.

Comment: @APC yeah, it's the client, he did some changes, i don't know why they allow them to.